# Root Context on EAP not getting registered in MOD_CLUSTER

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, jboss-eap-6, mod-cluster

I have setup two EAP instances in `standalone-ha` mode running as cluster.
I have also deployed an applicaiton with default / context (ROOT context) on both the nodes

I also setup `Apache MOD_CLUSTER` listening on `1994` port.

I am able to access the default context application directly by accessing the EAP nodes.

But, when I try to access the same default context application using Apache MOD_CLUSTER, I am not able to access it.

I am able to access applications running in contexts other than default context without any issue.

Following the link here: https://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.2.0/html_single/

I tried setting up the following option in my standalone.bat but its not working?

```
set "JAVA_OPTS= -Djboss.mod_cluster.excludedContexts=admin-console,invoker,jbossws,jmx-console,juddi,web-console %JAVA_OPTS%" 

The EAP version used is : 6.4.0
Apache MOD_CLUSTER version: is mod_cluster-1.2.6.Final.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwite excluded-contexts attribute in AS7 (EAP) mod_cluster subsystem, see [the docs](http://modcluster.io/documentation/#excluded-contexts). The ROOT is excluded by default.

Please, do not use mod_cluster 1.2.6, use mod_cluster 1.3.8 on the httpd side. 1.2.6 is many years old, it contains several high profile CVEs and performance issues.